# How to get date range - weekly wise from the month using javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, angular

How to get date range in weekly wise from the month using javascript

Ex:
If we give month ( july) and year (2022) as input, need to get the following output.
Week1 - 03-07-2022 to 09-07-2022
Week2 - 10-07-2022 to 16-07-2022
Week3 - 17-07-2022 to 23-07-2022
Week4 - 24-07-2022 to 30-07-2022

Pls suggest your ideas.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a date management library like `moment` (deprecated) or `dayjs`, which will allow you to find the start and end dates of each week in a month.

Sample code:

```
findWeeks() {
  const format = "DD-MM-YYYY"; 
  const date = "2022-07-01";
  let runningDate = dayjs(date);

  // Find if first day of the month is Sunday, else go to the date that is sunday
  if (dayjs(date).get('day') !== 0) {
    runningDate = dayjs(date).endOf('week');
    runningDate = dayjs(runningDate).add(1, 'day');
  }

  const weeks = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    weeks.push(
      `Week ${i}: ${dayjs(runningDate).format(format)} - ${dayjs(runningDate).add(6, 'day').format(format)}`
    );

    // move runningDate to start of week 2
    runningDate = dayjs(runningDate).add(7, 'day');
  }

  console.log(weeks);
}
```

[image]